# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition'

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I installed visual studio 2015 Pro update 3 and DotNetCore.1.0.0-VS2015Tools.Preview2.0.1 after finished installing restarted the PC. Before installing these the solution was working fine.

If I build a solution I get the following output: 
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition, Version=14.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

In Web.config under assemblyBinding there's no dependentAssembly for Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition

I have tried as many suggestions from Google including this one: [Could not load file or assembly… NuGet Assembly Redirects](http://blog.myget.org/post/2014/11/27/Could-not-load-file-or-assembly-NuGet-Assembly-Redirects.aspx) and all similar questions on StackExchange never helped.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried following ?

**Step 1:**

> Goto Visual studio > Properties > shortcuts tab > Advanced > Check
>   “Run As Administrator”

**Step 2:**

> Goto Visual studio > Tools > Extensions And Updates > Updates > Visual
>   Studio Gallery > Nuget Package Manager For Visual Studio 2015 > Update

Above two steps worked for me. You can try.
Please ignore if you already tried.

Comment: @haridarshan I couldn't find a fix but I ended up refreshing everything including my PC and reinstall Visual Studio and things got back to normal but I really could't figure out what was causing the error.